# Mumford's intuition for flatness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, intuition

In Mumford's book Algebraic Geometry II, he writes on page 179..."In order to get at what I consider the intuitive content of "flat" we need first a deeper fact..."

After the deeper fact is proven he states a corollary:

Corollary: Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ and let $ B = A[x_1, \cdots, x_n]_{\mathfrak{p}} $ where $ \mathfrak{p} \cap A = \mathfrak{m}$. Let $ f_1, \cdots, f_k \in B$. Then $B / (f_1, \cdots , f_k)$ is a flat $A$-algebra if and only if For all syzygies $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \bar{g}_i \bar{f}_i = 0 $ in $ B/ \mathfrak{m}B$ there exists a syzygy $ \sum_{i =1} ^{k} g_i f_i = 0$ in $ B$ with$ g_i$ lifting $\bar{g}_i$.

After this corollary he writes: "Flatness means that syzygies for the fibers lift to syzygies for the whole scheme and hence restrict to syzygies for the other fibers: certainly a reasonable continuity property."

I am not really geometrically minded and don't really understand this last quotation. In particular how are the hypothesis of the corollary realized if I just have a flat morphism $ f : X \longrightarrow Y$ of schemes? I don't see how to recover mumfords statement. Also there are some examples afterwards but they don't seem to cite the corollary above.

Comment: The corollary is a criterion for when a locally finitely presented morphism is flat.  Given a factorization of $f$ (locally) as the composite of an immersion $i:X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_Y$ followed by projection $\mathbb{A}^n_Y\to Y$, it is a criterion for flatness in terms of lifting a presentation for the ideal of the fiber $i_\mathfrak{m}:X_\mathfrak{m} \to \mathbb{A}^n_{A/\mathfrak{m}}$ to a presentation of the ideal of $i$.

Comment: Thanks Jason! (if you decide to post this answer, I will accept it)